Можно ли как-то распаковать файл формата h5
У меня есть файл нейросети который хранится в формате h5, есть ли возможность как-то его распаковать чтобы увидеть код?

.h5 хранит веса для логической сетки, но не её структуру, поэтому ответ - нет
